# CSV Import: undefined method `path', Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import

I am trying to import a CSV with employees. I am requiring 'csv' at the controller. However I get this error:

```
undefined method `path' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x00007fad5592b328>
```

[image]
Here are my routes

```html
  resources :employees do
resources :contrats, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

  end

   resources :employees do
resources :contratcdds, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

  end
resources :employees do
  collection { post :import }
end
```

Here is the method import in the controller

```html
require 'csv'
  def import
    Employee.import(params)[:file]
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Import réussi"
  end
```

Here is what is in my models. I think the problem come from here.

```html
  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers:true) do |row|
    Employee.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
```

And here is my view:

```html
  <%= form_tag import_employees_path, multipart: true do %>
      <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import CSV", class: "btn-medium" %>
  <% end %>
```

I am really lost, some can help me?

Warm regards.

Comment: You say `Employee.import(params)[:file]` but maybe you want something more like `Employee.import(params[:file])`?

Comment: You are having problems with syntax. Apart from what @muistooshort mentioned, your `CSV.foreach` should be `CSV.each` and indentation issue too.

Comment: @ARK I'm pretty sure the [`CSV.foreach`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach) is fine, but yeah, the indentation could be more consistent.

Comment: @muistooshort yeah my bad. Learnt a lesson. Almost googled before commenting but didn't. Should have.

Answer (score 1):

`Employee.import(params[:file])`

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.